# Does `git grep` on a remote actually search over the network?

Tags: git

Does using `git grep` on a remote actually search the remote system, or does it search the branch stored on the local machine?

```
git grep 'huntfor' 'refs/remotes/origin/main'

git grep 'huntfor' $(git ls-remote . 'refs/remotes/*' | ForEach-Object {($_ -split "`t")[1]})
```

Comment: Turn off the network and find out?

Comment: @matt, a simple yes or no would suffice. Or, can we not be that straightforward here?

Comment: `refs/remotes` is not really the *remote* branch; it's your local copy of the remote branch, as of the last fetch performed. The *only* operations Git can perform involving an external repository are fetch, pull, push, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git grep` only searches the working tree and index unless you specify a revision, and as such, it normally only searches files and revisions that you have on your local machine.  If your repository doesn't have the revision, then you can't search for it.

*However*, if you're using partial clone, your repository may contain a promisor pack from a certain remote (called the promisor remote), in which case Git will pretend that it has the objects in question and download them on demand if they're missing.  In such a case, if you have a promisor object for a particular revision that you're requesting, Git may connect to the promisor remote to fill in the relevant objects.  However, other changes on the remote that you haven't downloaded promisor objects for (such as changes that have occurred since a `git fetch` or `git pull`) will still not be accessible.

Comment: It sounds like if no revision is specified, that `git grep` will not access a remote repo over the network. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that should be the case, since the objects specified in the index should all be local (as they would have been present when you ran the checkout).  In general, `git grep` will never access the network unless you're using partial clone.